# Java ForEach in ArrayList with Locate

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, foreach

**Overview:**

I'm using for-each loops and I'm curious if I need to replace them with regular `for` loops, or if there is a way to do a locate in an `ArrayList` which will give me the equivalent of keeping track of the index which is used in normal `for` loops.

**Simplified Version of the Problem:**

I'm using for-each with an `ArrayList` of objects. These objects are used to calculate different values at different times, so I need to iterate through the items and do the calculates a couple different times. I wish to track these results in a structure, which I can easily do, if I can locate items in an `ArrayList` (without having to iterate through everything in a separate loop). If there is, then I can use that to build what I need. If not, I'll replace the for-each with `for` loops and get the functionality I need.

Comment: Locate them how? `indexOf()`?

Comment: For complex objects, to locate an element in a `List`, based on a particular member, you can override the `equals` method in the parameterized class to match with the specific thing (an id member for example). Then, `yourList.contains(new YourClass(4));`. It's not applicable with all cases but should be usefull.

Comment: @VenomFangs I don't know what you want to do but indexOf can be a fairly expensive operation depending on the size of the list and the type of objects in the list.

Comment: @VenomFangs You have `lastIndexOf` also, if you need to get the last occurrence of an element.

Comment: Arshajii's answer gives me what I need without the expensive operations :) Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* use a regular `for`-loop but sometimes it just isn't a good idea, for example if you're dealing with linked lists where element retrieval is O(n) in the index. Why not just keep track of index?

```
int index = 0;
for (Element e : list) {
    ...
    index++;
}
```

I find this cleaner than a plain `for`-loop, and it will remain efficient even if you change from `ArrayList` to another type of list which is not random-access.

Comment: This gives me what I need with minimal code change and will small operation costs. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

The `for-each` loop is meant to be an easy way to operate on every element in a collection or array. If you want to iterate and keep track of indicies, you'll want a normal `for` loop.

However, some `Collections` (`List`s for example) have an `indexOf()` method which you can use to get the index. That would kill your performance though.

You can also use a counter:

```
int i = 0;
for (Object o : list) {
    // Code
    i++;
}
```